# Custom Report - extract to new book instead of new sheet PAX IBM Planning Analytics

Tags: cognos-tm1

I'm working on the PAX IBM Planning Analytics (moved from using Perspectives).
Is there a way to do a cube report (custom report/any cube report) and have it exported to a new "book" instead of a "new sheet in the existing book".
It get's a bit frustrating having multiple workbooks open and not realizing where the cube viewer exported the view.
Thanks, Gem

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your issue.
It's possible to make active report in PAX easily. The best way is to create a cube view from the cube that you want and make a report based on this cube. I can help you if you give me more information about what you're try to do.

Comment: The issue isn't finding the right information or trying to create a cube view. The issue is not being able to export the cube view into a new "WorkBook", ie if I have an existing file open, I don't want to add extra sheets to it. I want a fresh blank file with only the cube view extract. ie just like how Perspectives used to do it. New Book with 1 sheet of my cube view. Therefore I don't need to start sifting through 10 files that are opened to see where it landed.

Comment: Also, it's not really an issue, I'm just asking if it's possible, so I can stop searching for answers that don't exist.

Comment: I think you can, but the view in your excel need to be an active report.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the report extract buttons can extract to a new work book. It's fundamentally different to how snapshots work in perspectives, where it creates a new book for the snapshot report. Ie perspective creates a separate book from what already is open.